# Bochner measurability

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, banach-spaces, lebesgue-measure

I have the following problem.
Let $(\Sigma, \Omega, \mu)$ be a measure space and let $X$ be a Banach space. 
Take a function $f \colon \Omega \rightarrow \mathbf{B}(X)$, which takes values in space of bounded linear operators on $X$. Are these two statements equivalent:

1) $f$ is Bochner measurable;

2) the map $\Omega \ni x \mapsto \| f(x)u \|$ is $\mu$-measurable, for all $u \in X$.

My hunch is that 1) implies 2), but 2) does not imply 1), can any one confirm.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I might be wrong but it seams to me, that 2) does not imply 1) even for normal Lebesgue integral. Take $M\subset \Omega$ non-measurable, define $f(x) = 2\chi_M(x) -1 $. Than $f$ is not measurable but $|f|$ is measurable.

Comment: Of course you are right, I didn't think about the easiest counterexample! Thanks.

Comment: But it would be interesting to know if it holds for integrability, provided you know that the function is measurable.